# Use argument ruby as a hash key

Tags: ruby

I want to create a code to name organic chemestry compounds. How can I use the arguments (num, bond) as keys for the hash? Ignore what I did to global variables, it's just to have a general idea of what I intent to do.

```
class Molecule
def molecule_name(num, bond)
   @num = { 1 => 'met', 2 => 'et', 3=> 'prop', 4 => 'but'}
   @bond = {1 => 'ano', 2 => 'eno', 3 => 'ino'}
end
a = Molecule.new; a = a.molecule_name(2,1)
print a
end
```

Comment: Still your intent is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do here? What is the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean just using `[]` e.g. `@num[num]` etc.?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What are you expecting `a.molecule_name(2,1)` to return? Something like `["et", "ano"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little unclear, but I think this is roughly what you're trying to achieve:

```
class Molecule
  def initialize(num, bond)
    @num = num
    @bond = bond
  end

  NAMES = {1 => 'met', 2 => 'et', 3 => 'prop', 4 => 'but'}
  BONDS = {1 => 'ano', 2 => 'eno', 3 => 'ino'}

  def molecule_name
    [ NAMES[@num], BONDS[@bond] ]
  end
end

a = Molecule.new(2, 1)
a.molecule_name # => ["et", "ano"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify as little as possible and still get a working example :

```
class Molecule
  attr_reader :num, :bond
  def to_s
    "#{@num}, #{@bond}"
  end

  def molecule_name(num, bond)
    @num = { 1 => 'met', 2 => 'et', 3=> 'prop', 4 => 'but'}[num]
    @bond = {1 => 'ano', 2 => 'eno', 3 => 'ino'}[bond]
  end
end 

a = Molecule.new
a.molecule_name(2,1)
puts a
#=> et, ano
puts a.num
#=>et
puts a.bond
#=>ano
```

This example would be a bit more Ruby-ish :

```
class Molecule
  attr_reader :num, :bond
  @@nums = { 1 => 'met', 2 => 'et', 3=> 'prop', 4 => 'but'}
  @@bonds = {1 => 'ano', 2 => 'eno', 3 => 'ino'}

  def initialize(num_id, bond_id)
    @num = @@nums[num_id]
    @bond = @@bonds[bond_id]
  end

  def name
    "#{num}, #{bond}"
  end
end 

a = Molecule.new(2,1)
puts a.name
```